# apache poi jar missing class files

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi, missing-features

I just started using the Apache POI library for dealing with .xls and .xlsx files. I got the `poi-ooxml-3.11.jar` file from their [maven repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/) and tried the example found [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/). When implemented in Eclipse, the import for the Row class was not resolved. I have checked the .jar file of the library and indeed under `apache.poi.ss.usermodel.` there is only one class `WorkbookFactory.class`. I have tried also previous versions of that POI library but I have stopped at 3.8 seeing that there is nothing in that package. The build path of the project in Eclipse is fine, everything is checked. I tried also with the `poi-bin-3.11-20141221.zip` library referenced, no success. Even in their library documentation found [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html) that class should be there. Any ideas? Do i have to get the sources and create a jar myself? Any suggestions are appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you are missing http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi/3.0-FINAL/

Comment: Nope. It is a different Row class. I need the one specified in the documentation. Please refer to my documentation link.

Comment: _poi-ooxml-3.11.jar_ depends on _poi-3.11.jar_ which does contain the class you need. The javadoc link you mention is the one from the _poi_ artifact, not the _poi-ooxml_

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thank you. If you can put it as a formal answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache POI is distributed in various modules, with a main one being *poi*.
Most of the other modules, including *poi-ooxml* do depend on this main artifact. The dependency is clearly stated in the [poi-ooxml POM](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.11/poi-ooxml-3.11.pom)

The best thing to do is let Maven handle this, it will automatically pull the needed dependendencies if you add the *poi-ooxml* one inside your POM.

If this is not possible, then you will have to replicate the dependency tree by inspecting the POM's of the libraries you need.

Comment: FYI As well as being detailed in the Maven POM, a more human-readable version of the dependency information is available on the [Apache POI Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)